# How to solve mysql more than 15 subquery “ subquery returns more than 1 row” error

Tags: mysql, database

```
SELECT et.*,
(SELECT el.waitTime FROM entityleg as el WHERE et.tripId=el.tripId LIMIT 1) AS leg1_waittime, 
(SELECT el.mode FROM entityleg as el WHERE et.tripId=el.tripId LIMIT 1) AS leg1_mode, 
(SELECT el.time FROM entityleg as el WHERE et.tripId=el.tripId LIMIT 1) AS leg1_time, 
(SELECT el.fare FROM entityleg as el WHERE et.tripId=el.tripId LIMIT 1) AS leg1_fare,
(SELECT el.waitTime FROM entityleg as el WHERE et.tripId=el.tripId LIMIT 1,1) AS leg2_waittime, 
(SELECT el.mode FROM entityleg as el WHERE et.tripId=el.tripId LIMIT 1,1) AS leg2_mode, 
(SELECT el.time FROM entityleg as el WHERE et.tripId=el.tripId LIMIT 1,1) AS leg2_time, 
(SELECT el.fare FROM entityleg as el WHERE et.tripId=el.tripId LIMIT 1,1) AS leg2_fare,
(SELECT el.waitTime FROM entityleg as el WHERE et.tripId=el.tripId LIMIT 1,2) AS leg3_waittime, 
(SELECT el.mode FROM entityleg as el WHERE et.tripId=el.tripId LIMIT 1,2) AS leg3_mode, 
(SELECT el.time FROM entityleg as el WHERE et.tripId=el.tripId LIMIT 1,2) AS leg3_time, 
(SELECT el.fare FROM entityleg as el WHERE et.tripId=el.tripId LIMIT 1,2) AS leg3_fare,
(SELECT el.waitTime FROM entityleg as el WHERE et.tripId=el.tripId LIMIT 1,3) AS leg4_waittime, 
(SELECT el.mode FROM entityleg as el WHERE et.tripId=el.tripId LIMIT 1,3) AS leg4_mode, 
(SELECT el.time FROM entityleg as el WHERE et.tripId=el.tripId LIMIT 1,3) AS leg4_time, 
(SELECT el.fare FROM entityleg as el WHERE et.tripId=el.tripId LIMIT 1,3) AS leg4_fare
FROM entitytrip as et
```

Comment: What are you trying to do?

Seems that you are making SELECT for each column in the same table which is crazy

Comment: this is requirement to create view like this ....

Answer (score 0):

Without trying to understand what you want to do, i see that the last 8 subqueries have a limit of 1,2 or 1,3. Those subqueries will return more than one row so you better change it to 2,1 & 3,1

```html
SELECT et.*,
(SELECT el.waitTime FROM entityleg as el WHERE et.tripId=el.tripId LIMIT 1) AS leg1_waittime, 
(SELECT el.mode FROM entityleg as el WHERE et.tripId=el.tripId LIMIT 1) AS leg1_mode, 
(SELECT el.time FROM entityleg as el WHERE et.tripId=el.tripId LIMIT 1) AS leg1_time, 
(SELECT el.fare FROM entityleg as el WHERE et.tripId=el.tripId LIMIT 1) AS leg1_fare,
(SELECT el.waitTime FROM entityleg as el WHERE et.tripId=el.tripId LIMIT 1,1) AS leg2_waittime, 
(SELECT el.mode FROM entityleg as el WHERE et.tripId=el.tripId LIMIT 1,1) AS leg2_mode, 
(SELECT el.time FROM entityleg as el WHERE et.tripId=el.tripId LIMIT 1,1) AS leg2_time, 
(SELECT el.fare FROM entityleg as el WHERE et.tripId=el.tripId LIMIT 1,1) AS leg2_fare,
(SELECT el.waitTime FROM entityleg as el WHERE et.tripId=el.tripId LIMIT 2,1) AS leg3_waittime, 
(SELECT el.mode FROM entityleg as el WHERE et.tripId=el.tripId LIMIT 2,1) AS leg3_mode, 
(SELECT el.time FROM entityleg as el WHERE et.tripId=el.tripId LIMIT 2,1) AS leg3_time, 
(SELECT el.fare FROM entityleg as el WHERE et.tripId=el.tripId LIMIT 2,1) AS leg3_fare,
(SELECT el.waitTime FROM entityleg as el WHERE et.tripId=el.tripId LIMIT 3,1) AS leg4_waittime, 
(SELECT el.mode FROM entityleg as el WHERE et.tripId=el.tripId LIMIT 3,1) AS leg4_mode, 
(SELECT el.time FROM entityleg as el WHERE et.tripId=el.tripId LIMIT 3,1) AS leg4_time, 
(SELECT el.fare FROM entityleg as el WHERE et.tripId=el.tripId LIMIT 3,1) AS leg4_fare
FROM entitytrip as et
```

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT et.*,
(SELECT el.waitTime FROM entityleg as el WHERE et.tripId=el.tripId LIMIT 1) AS leg1_waittime, 
(SELECT el.`mode` FROM entityleg as el WHERE et.tripId=el.tripId LIMIT 1) AS leg1_mode, 
(SELECT el.`time` FROM entityleg as el WHERE et.tripId=el.tripId LIMIT 1) AS leg1_time, 
(SELECT el.fare FROM entityleg as el WHERE et.tripId=el.tripId LIMIT 1) AS leg1_fare,
(SELECT el.waitTime FROM entityleg as el WHERE et.tripId=el.tripId LIMIT 1,1) AS leg2_waittime, 
(SELECT el.`mode` FROM entityleg as el WHERE et.tripId=el.tripId LIMIT 1,1) AS leg2_mode, 
(SELECT el.`time` FROM entityleg as el WHERE et.tripId=el.tripId LIMIT 1,1) AS leg2_time, 
(SELECT el.fare FROM entityleg as el WHERE et.tripId=el.tripId LIMIT 1,1) AS leg2_fare,
(SELECT el.waitTime FROM entityleg as el WHERE et.tripId=el.tripId LIMIT 2,1) AS leg3_waittime, 
(SELECT el.`mode` FROM entityleg as el WHERE et.tripId=el.tripId LIMIT 2,1) AS leg3_mode, 
(SELECT el.`time` FROM entityleg as el WHERE et.tripId=el.tripId LIMIT 2,1) AS leg3_time, 
(SELECT el.fare FROM entityleg as el WHERE et.tripId=el.tripId LIMIT 2,1) AS leg3_fare,
(SELECT el.waitTime FROM entityleg as el WHERE et.tripId=el.tripId LIMIT 3,1) AS leg4_waittime, 
(SELECT el.`mode` FROM entityleg as el WHERE et.tripId=el.tripId LIMIT 3,1) AS leg4_mode, 
(SELECT el.`time` FROM entityleg as el WHERE et.tripId=el.tripId LIMIT 3,1) AS leg4_time, 
(SELECT el.fare FROM entityleg as el WHERE et.tripId=el.tripId LIMIT 3,1) AS leg4_fare
FROM entitytrip as et
```

Here is the corrected code. Since **time** and **mode** are already predefined in mysql. So for mysql to understand it as a column name you have to use **`time`** and **`mode`**.

Also error "subquery returns more than 1 row" occured, since you misplaced limit and offset.Instead of `limit 2,1` you used `limit 1,2`. Similarly `limit 3,1` you used `limit 1,3`